# Spring Security oauth2 redirects to login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, okta

Attempting to integrate Okta into my Spring Web MVC application. Since I'm not using Spring Boot, I'm forced to follow the example in this link at the very bottom: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/oauth2login

So this is what I have:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("#{environment['okta.client-id']}")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("#{environment['okta.client-secret']}")
    private String clientSecret;
    @Value("#{environment['okta.redirect-uri']}")
    private String redirectUri;
    @Value("#{environment['okta.authorization-uri']}")
    private String authorizationUri;
    @Value("#{environment['okta.token-uri']}")
    private String tokenUri;
    @Value("#{environment['okta.user-info-uri']}")
    private String userInfoUri;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .clients(clientRegistrationRepository())
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .userInfoTypeConverter(
                        new UserInfoConverter(),
                        new URI(userInfoUri));
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        List<ClientRegistration> clientRegistrations = Collections.singletonList(clientRegistration());

        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrations);
    }

    private ClientRegistration clientRegistration() {

        return new ClientRegistration.Builder(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
                .authorizedGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUri(redirectUri)
                .scopes("openid", "email", "profile")
                .authorizationUri(authorizationUri)
                .tokenUri(tokenUri)
                .userInfoUri(userInfoUri)
                .clientName("Okta")
                .clientAlias("okta")
                .build();
    }
}
```

However, as soon as I log in sucessfully with Okta, it redirects me back to the login page: (http://localhost:8081/login). Clicking the Okta button to login again also redirects me to the same page.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: well obviously your application does not thing that you have logged in, most likely some configuration issue. I would check one of the spring security config classes for any *loggers* and turn on debug logging for those

Comment: @Zilvinas how come it wouldn't redirect me back to the Okta's login page if my app doesn't think I'm logged in?

Comment: just saying that you most likely you have some config issue; like a typo or smth

Comment: I've been able to make this work with Okta by copying the example's code and specifying my Okta settings in `application.properties`. Have you tried that approach? It seems there are a couple auto-configuration classes that you need in your project for things to work.